# Concerning paths of particles and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

It is well know that scientific tools , eg bubble chamber, can keep track of particle trajectories. Now here is my doubt. Quantum mechanics, which is a statistical theory, says that trajectories do not exist, eg electrons do not describe defined orbits around the nucleus. So how quantum mechanics reconcile with the presence of well defined paths experimentally observed by instrument used in particle physics? Scientific references would be strongly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does quantum mechanics imply that particles have no trajectories?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186170/)

Comment: There is a famous paper by Mott from the 30s, IIRC, which deals how trajectories in bubble chambers emerge. As a general remark, note that it is still an open problem to fully explain the classical (macroscopic) world from quantum mechanics.

Comment: Just downloaded the paper by Mott, thank you

Comment: Relevant answers 
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768504/28512
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/237872/28512